# Count the number of files in a folder by date

Tags: file, perl, count, directory

I need to count the number of files in a folder by date using Perl. Here is my code:

```
my $datestring = localtime(time); 
print "$datestring\n"; 
sub demFile { 
    $dir = "/root/perl/*"; 
    my @file = glob($dir); 
    foreach(@file) { 
        $a = scalar(grep $_, @file) . "\n"; 
        return $a; 
    } 
}

$b = demFile(); 
print $b;
```

Comment: What is the purpose of `grep $_, @file`? It seems like and identity operator on `@file`. For example `grep { $_ } @lst` gives back the same `@lst`

Comment: @HåkonHægland `grep $_, @file` is not an identity operator. For instance, `perl -E 'say join "-", grep $_, 1, 0, 2, "a", "", "c"'`. However, I'm not sure what purpose it serves in that question.

Comment: @Dada Good point!

Comment: You were probably thinking of `map $_, LIST`. But even that isn't quite equivalent to `LIST`. It creates a copy of the elements. This means that `$_=uc($_) for @a;` and `$_=uc($_) for map $_, @a;` are different. If you wanted a list operation that didn't create copies, you'd have to go with `grep 1, LIST` or `sub :lvalue { @_ }->(LIST)`.

Comment: Thank you very much! This is my new code : use Time::localtime;

$date = localtime();
print $date;
print "\n";
$dir = "/root/perl/*";
my @file = glob($dir);
$size = @file;
foreach (my $i=0; $i <= $size; $i++) {
        print @file[$i];
        print $size;
        print"\n";
}  
I will print the file names and paths, then the total number of files! 
But For example, I want to sum the files created yesterday, how to do it?

Comment: Thank you very much! This is my new code : use Time::localtime; $date = localtime(); print $date; print "\n"; $dir = "/root/perl/*"; my @file = glob($dir); $size = @file; foreach (my $i=0; $i <= $size; $i++) { print @file[$i]; print $size; print"\n"; }

Answer (score 3):

As with Kjetil S.'s solution, this one accepts file names rather than directory names to provide a much more flexible solution that the one you requested.

This version addresses a number of issues with Kjetil S.'s.

- It provides a minimalistic output consistent with the philosophy of using tool chains.
- It doesn't perform two stats per file.
- It doesn't skip non-directory, non-plain files.
- It handles errors.
- It's easier to read.

Example usage:

```
\ls                    | num_files_by_date
\ls /some/dir          | num_files_by_date
\ls -d /some/dir/*.txt | num_files_by_date
find dir1 dir2         | num_files_by_date
```

Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use File::stat qw( stat );
use POSIX qw( strftime );

my %counts_by_date;
while (<>) {
    chomp;
    my $stat = stat($_)
       or do {
          warn("Can't stat \"$_\": $!\n");
          next;
       };

    ++$counts_by_date{ strftime("%F", localtime($stat->mtime)) }
       if !-d $stat;  # Don't count dirs.
}

printf("%s %s\n", $_, $counts_by_date{$_})
   for sort keys %counts_by_date;
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This is my new code : use Time::localtime;

$date = localtime();
print $date;
print "\n";
$dir = "/root/perl/*";
my @file = glob($dir);
$size = @file;
foreach (my $i=0; $i <= $size; $i++) {
        print @file[$i];
        print $size;
        print"\n";
}  
I will print the file names and paths, then the total number of files! 
But For example, I want to sum the files created yesterday, how to do it?

Answer (score 2):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings; use strict;
my($n,%n)=(0);
while(<>){
    chomp;
    next if !-f$_; #just count files, ignore dirs, symlinks etc
    my $mtime=(stat($_))[9];
    my @lt=localtime($mtime); $lt[5]+=1900; $lt[4]+=1;
    my $date=sprintf"%04d-%02d-%02d", @lt[5,4,3];
    $n{$date}++;
    $n++;
}
my @d=sort keys %n;
printf "Date $_ has %3d files\n",$n{$_} for @d;
print "A total of $n files between $d[0] and $d[-1]\n";
```

Save as `num_files_by_date.pl` and `chmod +x num_files_by_date.pl`. The program takes a list of files on STDIN and counts the number on each date. Run forexample like this:

```
\ls -1 | ./num_files_by_date.pl
\ls -d1 /root/perl/* | perl num_files_by_date.pl
find dir1/ dir2/ | ./num_files_by_date.pl
```

Output could be:

```
Date 2019-04-28 has   2 files
Date 2019-04-30 has   3 files
Date 2019-05-03 has   1 files
Date 2019-05-06 has   4 files
A total of 10 files between 2019-04-28 and 2019-05-06
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This is my new code : use Time::localtime;

$date = localtime();
print $date;
print "\n";
$dir = "/root/perl/*";
my @file = glob($dir);
$size = @file;
foreach (my $i=0; $i <= $size; $i++) {
        print @file[$i];
        print $size;
        print"\n";
}  
I will print the file names and paths, then the total number of files! 
But For example, I want to sum the files created yesterday, how to do it?

Comment: `find /dire/ctory/some/where -type f -daystart -mtime -2 -mtime +0 | wc -l`